# Is there a way to see support tickets by using a support number?

Tags: support

A few days ago an user claimed in a comment that I was a confirmed jackass and bully and he "proofed" it by publishing an email he said he received from the Stack Exchange team.

> This user has been suspended from participating on our site, and warned about continuing this abusive behavior. Unfortunately, we can't do much to stop jackasses from harassing you off-site, but rest assured we're not sharing any of your private information with him (not that we have much to begin with). Please let us know if this behavior continues. Regards, -The Stack Exchange Team

I was quite puzzled because I never was suspended (663 consecutive days now — I would had noticed even a suspension of several hours) and I never was warned about any behavior.

He also added a support number.

Of course I am not happy about his comments, but what me really makes me wonder: Did a Stack Exchange team member really call me jackass — and why?

But that is not really my question - this is:

Is there a way to use the support number to view any ticket/flag/… that was created back then and that has something to do with it? I would really like to know, why I might have been identified as a jackass or if it is just some sort of misunderstanding. If so I would like to correct it. But I don't want to bother the Stack Exchange team for now.

Comment: Sounds like a user just making stuff up.

Comment: I just realized that this so-called support number starts with a valid date: 20130419XXXX. Even if this would be a valid number, it can't be a number from that time we clashed (because I had deleted some unnecessary tags) as that happened in last August.

Comment: The user's profile rants about clashes with other users. Although the wording of the communication rings true, it may be discussing those interactions, not yours.

Comment: (If it were me, I'd have walked away at 15 comments into your most recent interaction, at the latest. That thread got nonconstructive pretty fast, and went downhill faster.)

Comment: I should had walk away after leaving my initial comment. In the end I dont have to care if some one else's app gets reject or not. and I dont have to care if the knowledge I provided is used or not. I should had — but I didn't…

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta thanks for correcting my question

Comment: That sounds awfully un-professional to be from StackExchange, given our policy on swearing.

Comment: We only call users Jackasses in chat.  I mean, we never do.  What is this, I don't even

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use timestamps in our emails to identify threads, but it's not really in any way reliable. We could theoretically have collisions and probably do - I don't pay much attention to that number when handling the emails. The only reason it's there is because a few of Gmail's quirks were interfering with our ability to track separate threads, well, separately.

This is also fairly recent. I think the timestamps were only introduced a couple months ago, give or take. Any emails from before that would not have any IDs beyond the sender and maybe the subject line.

We are currently looking at migrating our support system to something that's not a Gmail inbox shared by several people, so at that point we might start assigning case numbers... though there probably still won't be a public interface where you could see past cases.

> I would really like to know, why I might have been identified as a jackass or if it is just some sort of misunderstanding. If so I would like to correct it. But I don't want to bother the Stack Exchange team for now.

I'm on the Stack Exchange team, so you reached us regardless. :) I don't want to drag this out in public, though. If you want to email me (the address is in my profile, or email team@ and reference this thread) with actual details like the user name, I can look into this further.